# iOS 16.4.1, HTML 5 video autoplay not working again

Tags: html, ios, video

Here we are again. Latest iOS version has broken html5 video tag again. Poster appears with controls in the back. Any suggestions?

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" playsinline="" loop="" poster=""><source src="***.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

[image]

Comment: The problems seems related to CODEC and file size. I tried using .webm and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for autoplay not working is low power mode enabled on your iphone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Adding playsinline and turning off low power mode works for me.